How can I normalize vertex scores in a PySpark Pregel algorithm using the sum of neighboring vertex scores?
I’m implementing the Adsorption algorithm in PySpark using GraphFrames. My goal is to send each vertex’s score to its neighboring vertices, scaled by the edge weight, and then normalize each vertex’s score based on the sum of these weighted neighboring scores. I’ve set up message passing with vertex scores, but I’m struggling to incorporate edge weights and ensure that the normalization uses the neighboring scores rather than just the incoming messages. What is the best way to handle this in PySpark’s Pregel API?
My current implementation looks like this:
# top_edges_df
# +---+---+------+
#|src|dst|weight|
# +---+---+------+
# |1  |5  |1.09  |
# |1  |2  |1.0   |
# |2  |5  |1.0   |
# |2  |1  |1.0   |
# |3  |1  |0.09  |
# |3  |5  |0.09  |
# |4  |5  |0.2   |
# |5  |1  |1.09  |
# |5  |2  |1.0   |
# +---+---+------+

# vertices_df_graph
# +---+-------------------+
# | id|      initial_score|
# +---+-------------------+
# |  1|               0.09|
# |  2|                0.0|
# |  3|                0.0|
# |  4|                0.0|
# |  5|0.29000000000000004|
# +---+-------------------+


# GraphFrame creation
graph = GraphFrame(vertices_df_graph, top_edges_df)

# Pregel algorithm with normalization and extracting top neighbors
pregel = graph.pregel \
    .setMaxIter(NUM_ROUNDS) \
    .withVertexColumn(
        "new_score",
        F.col("initial_score"),  # Before aggregation, use the current score
        INJECTION_RATE * F.col("initial_score") + (1 - INJECTION_RATE) * F.coalesce(Pregel.msg(), F.lit(0))
    ) \
    .sendMsgToDst(Pregel.edge("weight") * Pregel.src("normalized_score")) \
    .aggMsgs(F.sum(Pregel.msg())) \
    .withVertexColumn(
        "normalized_score",  # New column for normalized score
        F.lit(0),  # Initialization (no normalization yet)
        F.col("new_score") / F.coalesce(Pregel.msg(), F.lit(1))
    )

# Run Pregel
result = pregel.run()

# Display the result with the updated normalized scores and top neighbors
result.select("id", "new_score", "normalized_score").show()

I know the following line isn't what i want as it takes the sum of the incoming messages and I want it to take the sum over the scores of the neighboring nodes.
 F.col("new_score") / F.coalesce(Pregel.msg(), F.lit(1))

I have also tried:
 F.col("new_score") / graph.vertices.groupBy("id").agg(F.sum("new_score"))

But this didn't work either as the vertices in graph.vertices dont contain the column "new_score" yet.
I also tried with a window specification over the "id" column, but this always led to a score of one as it took the src id's so it was basically dividing by it self.
Has anybody encountered a similar problem? Or knows how i could obtain the normalization over the 'neigbouring' nodes' scores?
